# How to update database configuration for Crystal Report with BusinessObjects Java SDK

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm trying to update database configuration of a report using BO 4.2 SDK. Here is what I have tried.

```
query=Select SI_NAME,SI_ID From CI_INFOOBJECTS Where SI_PROGID = 'CrystalEnterprise.Report' 
                                 And SI_NAME= {report_name} And SI_PARENTID={parent_id};
IInfoObjects results = iStore.query(query);
IInfoObject report=(IInfoObject) results.get(0);
```

Both

```
IProperties parentLogonInfo = report.getProcessingInfo().properties().getProperties("SI_LOGON_INFO");
```

and

```
IProperties parentLogonInfo = report.getProcessingInfo().properties();
```

return null.

How should I update properties for report?

Comment: Did you execute your query in Query Builder ?
(http://server:port/AdminTools/querybuilder/ie.jsp)
Did it return the data you expected ?

Comment: Yes, it returns the IInfoObject which has the report name, parentID, UID type etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specified query does not contain the SI_PROCESSINFO property. Therefore, you cannot retrieve it after the query is executed.

Add the SI_PROCESSINFO property to your select clause and you will be able to access it after the query is executed.

```
Select SI_NAME,SI_ID, SI_PROCESSINFO From CI_INFOOBJECTS Where SI_PROGID = 'CrystalEnterprise.Report' And SI_NAME= {report_name} And SI_PARENTID={parent_id}
```